# FindMaximum "is not a real number at" nrnum problem

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I'm experiencing a problem using FindMaximum that I don't understand (due to my newbie knowledge of Mathematica's syntax).  That is, FindMaximum sometimes returns a (correct) answer, but sometimes returns

> The function value *some number* i is not a real number at {t} = {*some number*}.

I have two defined functions:

```
Envelope[t_, A_] := Norm[MatrixExp[(A) t]];

MaxEnvelope[A_, tmax_] := FindMaximum[{First@Envelope[t, A], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t];
```

### Working

For an example matrix that "works":

```
A1={{-1, 15}, {0, -10}}
MaxEnvelope[A1, 5]
```

returns

```
{1.40801, {t -> 0.212153}}
```

which makes sense given the plot

```
Plot[Envelope[t, A1], {t, 0, 5}]
```

### Problem

For an example matrix that throws the error:

```
A2={{-0.293578, -0.880734}, {0.0103211, -0.344037}}
MaxEnvelope[A2,5]
```

returns

> FindMaximum::nrnum: "The function value -1.+4.54871*10^-9\ I is not a real number at {t} = {6.06351*10^-9}. "

There is clearly a maximum here though:

```
Plot[Envelope[t, A2], {t, 0, 5}]
```

The problem appears to be the { } that wrap *t* and what is clearly a real number.  But why does the first matrix work and the second one not?

Comment: I don't think the problem is the `{}`.  It's the non-zero imaginary part of the function value (hence it is not real).

Comment: Try `Clear[Envelope]; Envelope[t_?NumericQ, A_] := Norm[MatrixExp[(A) t]];`

Comment: That worked!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `?NumericQ` to control evaluation fixes the problem.  The reason is somewhat subtler than usual and is discussed below.  I also removed the `First` from `MaxEnvelope`; it seemed to me to be a left-over from the OP trying to deal with the problem.

```
Clear[Envelope];
Envelope[t_?NumericQ, A_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Norm[MatrixExp[(A) t]];

MaxEnvelope[A_, tmax_] := FindMaximum[{Envelope[t, A], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t];

A2 = {{-0.293578, -0.880734}, {0.0103211, -0.344037}};
MaxEnvelope[A2, 5]

(*  {1.15797, {t -> 2.06801}}  *)
```

The use of `?NumericQ` is discussed in
[What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)
Here the reason it works is somewhat different than the usual reasons that one needs to control evaluation.

The problem comes from round-off error in evaluating `Norm` on a symbolic matrix with approximate coefficients.  First, a matrix with a symbol `t`:

```
Norm[MatrixExp[(A2) t]] /. t -> 1.
```

> Max::nord: Invalid comparison with 0.476429 -6.71157*10^-18 I attempted. >>
>   Max::nord: Invalid comparison with 1.1094 +1.19767*10^-17 I attempted. >>

```
(*  Max[0.476429 - 6.71157*10^-18 I, 1.1094 + 1.19767*10^-17 I]  *)
```

Next, with a completely numeric matrix:

```
Norm[MatrixExp[(A2) t] /. t -> 1.]
(*  1.1094  *)
```

If we inspect the result of `Norm` in the first example, we can see the problem.  There are some small imaginary parts and some unevaluated `Conjugate` expressions (`Short` form shown):

```
 Norm[MatrixExp[(A2) t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Evidently, `Norm` does some processing on the symbolic matrix and there is round-off error in computing the coefficients.  When this complex-valued expression is passed to `FindMaximum` there are problems.  (The `First@Envelope[..]` in the OP can be seen to pick out the first argument to the expression `Max[..]` returned by `Norm`.)

The fix, `t_?NumericQ` and `A_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)`, ensures that `MatrixExp[(A) t]` is a completely numeric matrix before passing it to `Norm`.

Comment: The problem is also demonstrated by `SingularValueList[MatrixExp[A2 t], Tolerance -> 0] /. t -> 1.`; since `Norm[]` is equivalent to taking the maximum of that, the OP's problem is seen.